# Is it possible to use simple_list_item_multiple_choice in a listview found inside a dialog fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a DialogFragment class that has a Listview. What I want is for the Listview to have checkboxes so set the Listview *into simple_list_item_multiple_choice* however I get an null pointer exception error evrytime I click the element, here's my code so far..

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
OnItemClickListener {
    SharedPreferences dataattribute_pref;
    ArrayList<String> lstview_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> checkedAttrib;
    ArrayAdapter<String> lstview_adapter;
    ListView attributelist;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            dataattribute_pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefonDataAttribute", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dataatribute, null, false);
            attributelist = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lstview_AttributeList);
            Map<String,?> prefelement = dataattribute_pref.getAll();
            for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : prefelement.entrySet()){
                lstview_list.add(entry.getValue().toString());
            }

            /////////// .....


            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

         lstview_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, lstview_list);
         attributelist.setAdapter(lstview_adapter);
         attributelist.setOnItemClickListener(this);


     }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SparseBooleanArray checked=attributelist.getCheckedItemPositions();
        if(!checked.get(position)){
            checkedAttrib.remove(lstview_list.get(position));
        }
        else{
            checkedAttrib.add(lstview_list.get(position));
        }

    }

}
```

and here's how the interface looks like[image]

what it does is that it takes input from the user and dynamically add the user input in the list.. and whenever the user want to delete something from the list he/she can just check those item and click the trash bin button.. and I used the dialog fragment because I found it easy to use when it is called by another fragment..

can somebody please help.. please.. thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use isItemChecked(position) in item click listener :

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(!attributelist.isItemChecked(position)){
       checkedAttrib.remove(lstview_list.get(position));
    }else{
       checkedAttrib.add(lstview_list.get(position));
    }
 }
```